# Как выровнять текст в ячейке по вертикали (по верхнему краю)

Tags: c#, excel

Проект на `ASp.Net MVC4 c# + ms sql server 2008r2`. Вывожу отчеты в `Excell`. Работаю через библиотеку `NPOI.HPSF` (раньше работал через `Interrop` но в этом проекте приказ через `NPOI.HPSF`). Как сделать итлик или болд или текст по словам переносить разобрался, а вот как выровнять в ячейке текст по верхнему краю пока не нашел.
Поделитесь, пожалуйста, если кто с таким сталкивался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ICellStyle style2 = hssfworkbook.CreateCellStyle();
IFont font2 = hssfworkbook.CreateFont();
font2.Color = NPOI.HSSF.Util.HSSFColor.BLACK.index;
style2.SetFont(font2);
style2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.TOP;
```

нашел--вопрос снят